# Script that change to uppercase only one letter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to do a textbox that changes every "R" in a text, to uppercase. But there is some rules.

- if the R is the first letter, it maintains his original case;
- if 2 R's in a row, it maintains his original case;

Dont know where to start

Comment: What do you know about strings?

Comment: You could start by splitting over whitespace -> `"I am a string with white space. Hear me roar.".split(" ")`, then iterate over each one -> `[e for e in "I am a string with white space. Hear me roar.".split(" ")]` or `for e in "I am a string with white space. Hear me roar.".split(" "): print(e);`

Comment: @Shmack JS not Python

Comment: My bad, IDK how I missed that.

Comment: What is a "row"?

Answer (score -1):

this should answer your question, regex isnt easy. There might be a way to do it by getting the target group but so far can't figure that out.

```
example string 'road is very big Rr'
string.replace(/[^rR]([rR])[^rR]/g, str => { return str.replace("r","R")}  );
output string 'road is veRy big Rr'
```